How to store different types of logs in different files in Serilog .NET 8
I want to store logs in different file based on type.
Let's say for for

API Request log - request-.txt;
EF Core Query - log-.txt

I have installed Serilog packages, and it works fine but file contains all the logs.
<PackageVersion Include="Serilog" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageVersion Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageVersion Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageVersion Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageVersion Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="6.0.0" />

In my appSettings.json file, I tried using Expression.
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "shared": true,
          "flushToDiskInterval": 1
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncluding",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database')"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

But it didn't worked. All logs are storing into single log file log-{Date}.txt.
If there is no way to configure this in appSettings.json file, then how to configure in Program.cs file.

Hi JOYBOY, could you kindly check this answer?

Hello Jason, added condition in expression it worked.

Hi JOYBOY, thanks for your reply. May I know if my link inspired you?

@JasonPan, From your shared answer I got the intuition to add SourceContext condition.

Hi JOYBOY， could you share your solution as answer below, it may help other community users who face the same issue in the future.

Sure @JasonPan,
Here is what I've done in appSettings.json. I've used Serilog.Expressions NuGet package and wrote the condition using ByIncluding
"Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SourceContext = 'Pagila.API.Middlewares.HttpRequestLoggingMiddleware' or SourceContext = 'Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": []
}

Comment length constraint.
